# How do I Get Wordpress Featured image from Frontend

Tags: post-thumbnails

How do I get actual size i.e. 630x280 of featured image from wordpress frontend. I don't have access of backend and all. I just wanted to retrieved actual featured image from wordpress. Basically wordpress compress that image into thumbnail view But i want it's actual size. so anyone having idea how to get it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the original size with the following:

```
the_post_thumbnail( 'full' );
```